# Assemble oneliners from multiline PS script

Tags: powershell, cmd, one-liner

Need to manipulate ICS from command line batch script, but did not found suitable console tool. But found [powershell script](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/88003b3b-0e5c-49a7-bb20-cdbbbb435d09/enabling-windows-ics-from-powershell?forum=ITCG) which do such task. The problem is the script is multiline and as I have zero experiences with PS, looking for someone who could create few oneliners from such script to easily run trhough batch script and parse its output. Need following oneliners:

- List adapters with ICS enabled
- Enable ICS for specific interfaces
- Disable ICS on specific interface

Anyone could help me with this?

Comment: There is no benefit to using single lines, _(it will also make your script more difficult to read/modify/understand) too_. Also this site is not a code writing or conversion service, your question is therefore off topic here, _and as you're not a new member, you should be well aware of that, (downvoted)_.

Comment: As for this... [I have zero experiences with PS], everyone has been here but hey take the time to get ramped up on it. Visit YOutube and search for 'Beginning PowerShell'. If you made no effort to learn it the one-liners won't make any more sense. Never run anyone's code no matter where you get it from unless you know what it is doing, or accpt all consequences for using it whcih could seriouly damage your computer or your enterprise.

Comment: To futher clarify what @Campo is saynig.  SO has rules:  [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  --- your post is literally asking folks here to do your job/work for you. That's really not a thing. 
  Sometimes it does happen, but usually, only it is interesting to do.

Comment: Have network settings manipulating batch script performing several network related tasks. All tasks are done by console utilities but there are no such tools for ICS (and other issues), so I decided to incorporate PS in following manner:for /f %a in ('powershell.exe "oneliner performing single task and protuced parseable output"') do (process oneliner output) For this purpose I need split PS script into the serie of oneliners. This is no enough reason? I did this with several other PS scripts by myself but I waste hughe amount of time, much much more than experienced person kind to help.

Comment: @postanote If I have to decide between run non-understanded working code or spend a weeks or months (as I am not a cleverest_man_on_the_planet) to learn new programming language, I prefer the first option.I have other preferences on my life and is meaningless to push unknown people to spent their time to learn something. Anyhow my skils are not comparable to most people here, I trying to help other people here with their problems in batch scripting, the only "language" I know, without to push them to learn. I know you are watching "purity" of SO, but respect different approach people...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why on Earth would they need to be one-liners? None of these are suitable for one-liners, for instance your first one could look like this.

```
(New-Object -ComObject HNetCfg.HNetShare -OutVariable netshare).EnumEveryConnection | foreach {[PSCustomObject]@{Interface = $netshare.NetConnectionProps.Invoke($_).name; ICSEnabled = $netshare.INetSharingConfigurationForINetConnection.invoke($_).sharingenabled}}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly for wha I am looking. The (hope good one) reason for oneliner usage is in upper comment. I believe this could be useful for other people too.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid dot as a column separator? There are space in interface names thus is not easy to parse output in batch file. Column flip (ICSEnabled column first) will help too. Or maybe print interface index instead of interface name, but do not know about PS output formating possibilities. Just playing with `-OutputFormat` command, but have no luck..

Comment: Just found if `name` is replaced by `Guid`, parsing problem is solved!

Comment: It start display en error message for some reason: `Exception calling "Invoke" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot process argument because the value of argument
"arguments" is null. Change the value of argument "arguments" to a non-null value."
At line:1 char:96
+ ...  | foreach {[PSCustomObject]@{Interface = $netshare.NetConnectionProp ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSArgumentNullException`

Comment: Make sure to run as admin